# Transform shape of Functions returning Futures

Tags: scala, scalaz

```
def funct1 : Future[\/[Throwable,Address] ] ={}

def func2 : Future[\/[Throwable,Option[Person]] = {}
```

Now within `func2`

```
def func2 : Future[\/[Throwable,Option[Person]] = async{
 blocking{
  val person :Option[Person] = PersonDao.findByType("employee") 
  person.map{ p =>
   p.copy(addresses = func1Address) //need to call func1 and get Address out of it here
  }
 }
}
```

How do I get `func1Address` above? Trying to use `EitherT` from scalaz but it's not aligning correctly having no `Future` for `p` and `func1` is returning `Future[\/]`. What's the best way to do this?